# working with local Meteor package dependencies

Tags: meteor

I recently forked a package to modify it and then submit a pull request on it later.

On my project `smart.json` I defined it like this:

```
"autoform": {
  "path": "../meteor-autoform"
},
```

it works well, I see my modifications.

But I also need to modifications on a package that `autoform` depends on, so I did the same thing on `autoform`'s `smart.json` file:

```
"simple-schema": {
    "path":"../meteor-simple-schema"
  },
```

But when I run `mrt` to launch my app I got:

```
Problem installing simple-schema
✘ [/path/to/meteor-simple-schema] conflicts with [latest]
Can't resolve dependencies! Use --force if you don't mind mrt taking a wild guess and running your app anyway.
```

Used `--force` but did not help

Any idea ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably some other package depends on `simple-schema` and fetches the official version. Search your `/package` directory for `simple-schema` to find out. Also check whether your own `smart.json` or `smart.lock` doesn't ask for official `simple-schema`. If there's a trace of it in `smart.lock`, it is safe to remove that file.